# run @Component after @Repository in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, spring-bean

I'm using **Redis** in a spring project and I define a @Component class that uses Redis repository with @Autowire, but when debugging the application, @Component class constructor runs before bean to connect to Redis, therefore the application exits with this error :

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataManager' defined in file [/mnt/D/ms/projects/EventDetection/out/production/classes/ir/rahati/data/datamanager/DataManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ir.rahati.data.messagegraph.redis.RedisMessageGraphRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

DataManager class

```
@Component
public class DataManager {
        private final RedisMessageGraph messageGraph;
    @Autowired
    public DataManager( RedisMessageGraphRepository redisMessageGraphRepository) {
        this.messageGraph=new RedisMessageGraph(redisMessageGraphRepository);
    }
}
```

Redis repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface RedisMessageGraphRepository extends CrudRepository<MessageGraphModel, String> {
}
```

Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories("ir.rahati.data.messagegraph")
public class RedisMessageGraphConfig {
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(3);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }


    @Bean(name = "redis15")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());

        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that any parameters you're passing into bean constructors have to be initialized in a configuration. In my project I'm creating a DataSource bean in the configuration and passing it as a parameter into some Service constructors and it works well. It's just thinking aloud - have never deal with Redis before